# POST body not populating with PHP curl request set to application/json for TFS REST Endpoint

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, tfs

I'm struggling with a contradiction in expectations v. capabilities here, and hope that someone can help me out, or at least confirm that I'm not insane.

I'm attempting to build a two-way Slack integration with on on-premises Microsoft TFS REST endpoint, using Node.js and PHP as the main processors of the data to and from.  I can successfully perform GETs against the on-prem TFS install using NTLM authentication, and parse the data through to Slack.  So I know that (1) the endpoint is working, and (2) I am capable of authenticating to it.

However, in order to run a query against the TFS REST endpoint, you have to send a request that is content-type "application/json" or "application/json+patch".  No matter what I do, using curl in PHP or natively in the Node.js application, I cannot get the query to be sent in the body of the request to the endpoint.  Using another page to test this out, if I set the content-type to "multipart/form-data" or other standard types, I can send the body, but TFS will reject those requests as the wrong content-type.

Does anyone have any idea how to send a POST request that's both content-type "application/json" *and* will include the body using PHP or Node.js?

Here's the exact PHP that I've been using (which does not post a body, but does post data that can be read by PHP using file_get_contents('php://input')):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$baseURL);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postBody);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Transfer-Encoding: chunked',
    'x-metadata: testing',
    'x-testing: This is a value'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

And here's the error response from TFS:

"You must pass a query object in the body of the request."

If I change the remove the content-type header entirely, the body is sent (confirmed through another PHP page), but then I get this error from TFS:

"The request indicated a Content-Type of \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" for method type \"POST\" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are: application/json, application/json-patch+json."

**Update**

So I can get a request to pass a body to an http endpoint by using a custom request, but when it attempts to connect to the https endpoint hosting the TFS instance, all the headers are getting dropped, which returns the last error above.

Headers sent to https:

```
'request_header' => string 'POST /tfs/{PROJECT}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=2.0 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: NTLM {TOKEN}
```

Headers sent to http:

```
'request_header' => string 'POST /dev/tfs/post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: {HOST}
Accept: */*
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
x-metadata: testing
x-testing: This is a value
Content-Type: application/json
40
' (length=203)
```

Here is the updated PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$baseURL);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postBody);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Transfer-Encoding: chunked',
    'x-metadata: testing',
    'x-testing: This is a value'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

**Update #2**

Changing from "Content-Type:application/json" to "Accept:application/json" in the headers now makes the body post to the http endpoint, but the headers are still being dropped from the https endpoint.

**Update #3**
I can make successful requests to this endpoint using RESTlet within my Chrome browser, so it doesn't appear to be an issue with the TFS endpoint, but something in transfer between the PHP script and curl making the request.

Comment: Try removing 

```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);```

and adding

```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postBody));```

Comment: Just tried that, and for some reason connecting to the TFS endpoint (https) that's causing the headers to drop entirely, while it seems to work on a standard http connection (to another server).

'request_header' => string 'POST /tfs/[project]/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=2.0 HTTP/1.1
Authorization:NTLM [token]

HTTP Headers: 'request_header' => string 'POST /dev/tfs/post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.holyelvis.com
Accept: */*
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
x-metadata: testing
x-testing: This is a value
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

40
' (length=203)

Comment: Make sure you change that semicolon in your content-type header to a colon as well.

Here's a gist that I've tested makes a valid json request locally. Maybe you could work from there? https://gist.github.com/raddeus/a02c7fcb8ecec37c90f515dacc5fc506

Comment: Good catch - that fixed the http problem with the dropped content-type, but did not alter the behavior on the https side.

Comment: So, I was able to get the body to post over http using 'Accept: application/json' instead of 'Content-Type: application/json' but the headers continue to get dropped on the https connection for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the tips; I think I've narrowed it down to something happening when trying to pass the POST body through NTLM authentication via curl; I'll keep poking there to see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the request and response headers by adding the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)){
    echo 'Retreive Base Page Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else {
  $info = rawurldecode(var_export(curl_getinfo($ch),true));
  $skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
  $responseHeader= substr($data,0,$skip);

echo "<pre>$info\n================\n$responseHeader\n===============\n";
echo substr($data,$skip);
```